# Typo3 9.5 subclasses and foreign tables

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

How do I specify the foreign tables for attributes defined in subclasses, when using single table inheritance in Typo3 9.5?

I have the class inheritance defined in ext_typoscript_setup.txt:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistance.classes {
    MyProject\Base { mapping {
       tablename = tx_myproject_base
       subclasses = {
          1 = MyProject\Derived
       }
    }}
    MyProject\Derived { mapping {
       tablename = tx_myproject_base
       recordType = 1
       columns = {
           choice.mapOnProperty = selection
       }
    }}
    MyProject\Choice { mapping {
       tablename = tx_myproject_choice
   }}
}
```

In Configuration/TCA/tx_myproject_base.php, I have

```
return [
  'ctrl' => ['type' => 'subclass'],
  'columns' => [
     // some fields of the base type
     // and now the fields of the derived type
     'choice' => [
         'config' => [
           'type' => 'select',
           'foreign_table' => tx_myproject_choice,
           'size' => 1,
           'minitems' => 0, 'maxitems' => 1,
           'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
         ]
  ]]
];
```

So the Derived objects have a foreign key into Choice called choice in the database and selection in php.

When I do setOrderings('selection.ranking'=>DESCENDING) in a controller, I get the error

```
The relation information for property "selection" of class "MyProject\Derived" is missing.
```

In debug output, I see that the field is correctly mapped to the choice field, but the foreign_table information is missing.

I'm assuming the problem is that I have the TCA configuration for the subclass in the PHP file for the base table, but I don't know how to fix this.

How can I make Extbase understand that a field of the subtype is a key to a foreign model?

Comment: you can specify the key to your domain model. On your domain model you can add the 'selection' field with the type of inline if it is 1:n. If it is m:n then use select

Comment: You are right. I actually have this configuration of 'type' as 'select', and have updated the article accordingly.

Comment: Should I add this as an answer for the future developers? Did it work for you?

Comment: No. I actually had this configuration all the time, I just stripped it for the posting. It still doesn't work.